# Form closing before new shows

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012

Hello I'm making my first Windows Forms app in C# using Visual Studio and I have a little problem.

While I'm opening a new form and closing the previous one, when I run the app it looks like it's closing the previous form before it opens a new one.
It doesn't look good and I want to avoid it.

```
UserPanel MDIUserPanel = new UserPanel(Username);
MDIUserPanel.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
MDIUserPanel.Show();
this.Close();
```

I don't know what is going wrong. I will be thankful for any help.

Wirth regards,
DarQScreaM

@Edit

This doesn't seem to be the case actually. Propably its that :

I have 3 forms MainForm, Login, LoggedUser.

MainForm is MDI container with FormBorderStyle set on Fixed Single
Login is child of MainForm with FormBorderStyle set on None
LoggedUser is child of MainForm with FormBorderStyle set on None

When application is runned Login form is created in MainForm. MainForm is never closed since its container.

But when i move from Login form to LoggedUser form and vice-versa its created with FormBorderStyle = Fixed Single (normal windows window) and after 0.5~second its changed into None.

Editing it into that didn't really help :

```
MDIUserPanel.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
MDIUserPanel.Show();
```

@Edit2

This change fixed it for me. I don't know why setting it on Form properties didn't work properly. It looked like form was created as FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle and then it was changed into FormBorderStyle.None. If I made this manually in Load it worked but U had to fix the size of my window too. It doesn't seem to be good though. It should work from the beginning since Form properties in Designer are like that from the very beginning.

```
private void UserPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Size = new Size(649, 357);
}
```

Comment: No it happens on all forms. Not only on first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form's [Shown event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure that the new form have been showed before you close the old one.

```
UserPanel MDIUserPanel = new UserPanel();
MDIUserPanel.Shown += ((s, ee) =>
{
    this.Close();
});
MDIUserPanel.Show();
```

Comment: Ok i have tried that. It works the same. But that made me to notice the real problem.

My Parent is MDIContainer with :
FormBorderStyle : Fixed Single

My childs have :
FormBorderStyle : None

But when child is created and showed its created as FormBorderStyle : Fixed Single (normal windows window) and after 0.5 second border is erased.

Answer (score 0):

If this form you are trying to close, is the main form that opens when you run your application, then that's the reason. Closing the main form will exit your application. Try instead to just hide this form instead of closing it. And to make sure you can exit your application ('cause you've hidden your main form), just override the closing event of your current form, and put an "Application.Exit()" in it. 
Hope this helps you !

Comment: No I'm not closing the main form. Main form in my project is used as MDIContainer where child forms are being showed/closed.

Answer (score -1):

First Step:
`this.Hide();`

Second Step:
`MDIUserPanel.Show();`

Comment: I don't want previous forms to be hidden since in bigger app it can make situation when more than 10 windows will be "hidden". I think its too much resource consuming. Also its way easier to open new instance of this form and load updated date (if any were changed in other forms) than forcing update on hidden ones. I even don't know how to do that without giving reference to previous forms to the next one.

Comment: Then just do this,
First Step: this.Close();
Second Step: MDIUserPanel.Show();
This should work